# How to add version number to js and css files

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

I want to insert all my bower components into my index page with appropriate version suffixes. By version suffixes, I mean the version number in every component's specific `version` attribute in their `bower.json` file.

As an example,

I have jquery in my application's `bower.json` dependencies.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    }
}
```

And jquery component has its own `.bower.json` and that json has a `version` attribute.

```
{
  "name": "jquery",
  "main": "dist/jquery.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "2.2.0"
  // ETC...
}
```

What I want is to extract this version number from the component's `.bower.json` file and create a script tag like this

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js?version=2.2.0"></script>
```

I am using a gulp `wiredep` task to automatically insert my components in index.html. I can add custom suffixes to the src attribute of script tags by overriding options attribute of wiredep, using fileTypes attribute.

```
fileTypes: {
    html: {
        replace: {
            js: '<script src="{{filePath}}?v=0.1"></script>'
        }
    }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get the version number of each specific component and how to override them seperately when wiredep inserts them on the page.

Is my approach correct? Then, how can I proceed?
Or there is a better way to accomplish this...

**P.S. --** *This requirement is related to cache busting. But not at all. I'm using gulp-rev for cache busting my custom application js and css files. But bower componenets should not be cache busted in every build. I want to reference them with their version number and only use cache busting when I update them and cache bust using a new version suffix.*

Comment: Is this for cache busting?

Comment: Yes, it is. I know about "gulp-rev" for cache busting. But it always creates a new suffix for every build. I use gulp-rev for my custom css and js files. For bower components, I don't want to cache bust them.

Comment: gulp-cache-bust does cache busting based on the contents using MD5

Comment: That is good to know :) Will give that a go, definitely. Would you like to write an answer with some explanation on the subject? By the way, gulp-cache-bust is deprecated. May be another one which is still maintained?

Answer (score 2):

As requested --

There are several cache busting mechanisms that use checksums or hash of the data to implement cache busting that may suit your needs better than having to update a version number:

- gulp-cache-bust
- gulp-cachebust
- gulp-bust

are a few I found just doing a google search

The one I've used in the recent past is the first (gulp-cache-bust)